# Unix timestamp vs datetime

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, unix-timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Datetime vs Timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp)

I have a Mysql table, which has a column `add_date`. It tracks the date/time when the record was added to the database.

Queries based on this table:

1. Display when the record was added in the format: 2 hours ago, 4 weeks ago, 1 year ago etc
2. Allow users to search records inserted in any day/month/year. So the user may be allowed to choose to see the records inserted in 2009 only.

Which would be better in this case - unix timestamp or datetime?

Right now I'm using both, but since the table will have millions of records over time, having both columns may affect the size of the database.

Unix timestamp seem to be better for conversion to `2 hours` ago format in PHP and also it is timezone independent. But datetime has better readability and making a query for a particular date/time/year seems easier.

Your suggestion?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you have the choice, I'd say go for mySQL dates.

- You won't have to take care of [date range issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)s
- You can easily query time spans using mySQL's date functions (`BETWEEN(), DATE_ADD` etc.)
- Date related queries will be much faster, especially when you have millions of records, because you won't have to use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` which can be expensive in large queries
- It's child's play to convert DATE fields into UNIX timestamps when necessary.

Comment: This. Just use UNIX_TIMESTAMP(your_column) if you want to play with timestamp on the php end.
But in your database, use the native date type to store dates. Moreover, the data in your database may be used by other applications which may prefer SQL date format than timestamps.

Comment: Will there be any problem converting date to unix timestamps with respect to timezone?

Comment: @Lost_in_code good question actually. There is a number of factors involved, the timezone setting of the mySQL server, and the system's timezone setting that PHP will use by default. In general, mySQL DATETIME fields are timezone insensitive. As long as you store UTC dates there, you should be able to convert them into timestamps easily, but be careful if mySQL and/or PHP have time zones different from UTC.  Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449/dealing-with-php-server-and-mysql-server-in-different-time-zones

Answer (score 5):

I'd go for the mysql formats, just because mysql has a plenty of datetime function, to use which with timestamp will cost you another conversion.

> but since the table will have millions
>   of records over time, having both
>   columns may affect the size of the
>   database.

oh my.
are you really concerned in 4 additional megabytes of space?

Comment: I don't really know how much space would that take (I'm new to large databases). If you say it's just gonna be couple of MBs then I don't see a problem having both.

Comment: If you don't konw the number, you shouldn't mention it. No programmer should ever guess. It's weather forecasters job. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html will tell you that datetime take 8 bytes and int for timestamp - 4. so, 4 * 1000000 = less than 4Mb

Comment: You'll probably want to use an index on both of the fields as well. That's not too expensive spacewise, but if you're using multiple field indices it could impact your performance.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the best of both worlds by using a unix timestamp and the MySQL `from_unixtime()` function to convert the result to datetime format where needed.

Comment: You can also get the best of both worlds by using datetime and using the date functions to convert to unix timestamps when necessary.  Given that using datetime data types makes many queries easier, I'd say it's better to go that way.

Comment: What El Yobo says. Potential performance loss is what would make me shy away from `from_unixtime()` in big tables (Don't have any benchmarks though.)

Comment: Of course from_unixtime() shouldn't be used on queries that are expected to result large amounts of data, only ones that return result sets that are meant to be displayed. Also, datetime types can still be used to make queries more readable with unix_timestamp('2010-06-01 13:00'). The conversion is done only once per query so there's no performance loss.