# Timestamp off in sql database for PHP and Javascript Chat Room

Tags: php, javascript, sql, timezone, chatroom

Basically I have been trying to follow a tutorial to create a chatroom.

[Ajax Web Chat Tutorial](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/10/ajax-web-chat-php-mysql/)

I have it all done except the time is being displayed incorrectly and I can't figure out where to start.

STEP 1. The chat displays the user's line right away (displayed correctly using javascript's Date() so the user thinks the system is speedy and quick)

STEP 2. Then it goes to the database and stores the chatline where a column 'ts' stores the current_timestamp as a timestamp.

STEP 3. After that Ajax grabs the chatlines from the database and refreshes the chat to display the 'real' chat lines it is displayed incorrectly even though the code is supposed to convert it to the user's timeszone. Here is the code to give you a sense of where I am at.

Grab Time from chat database:
// Returning the GMT (UTC) time of the chat creation:

```
        $chat->time = array( 
            'hours'     => gmdate('h',strtotime($chat->ts)),
            'minutes'   => gmdate('i',strtotime($chat->ts))
        );
```

This is then sent to javascript to update the chatroom's chat lines

// All times are displayed in the user's timezone
        var d = new Date();

```
    if(params.time) {
        // PHP returns the time in UTC (GMT). We use it to feed the date
        // object and later output it in the user's timezone. JavaScript
        // internally converts it for us.

        d.setUTCHours(params.time.hours,params.time.minutes);
    }
    params.time = (d.getHours() < 10 ? '0' : '' ) + d.getHours()+':'+
                  (d.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0':'') + d.getMinutes();
```

EXAMPLE: User submits chatline..

Javascript Prints 11:07...

SQL saves current_timestamp as 8:07 ...

PHP grabs from database and converts it to 12:07

d.setUTCHours = 1348834072033

and lastly params.time is printed using javascript to 8:07

I don't think I'm missing anything else. Can anyone help? Really feel shitty trying to figure this out for a few days. Javascript is good... i think SQL is doing what its supposed to do and convert it to a universal time or something GMT? :P and PHP is close.. being an hour off but then javascript doesn't do what its supposed to do :(

Comment: Great... ok see currently I don't send a date to the server. It just uses 'current_timestamp' in mysql. I thought that was the most efficient way. I really don't like talking from javascript to php. Is there a php function that I can use instead of Date.UTC?

Answer (score 1):

There's, what, three different systems here? The web browser, the database and the web server (running PHP), right?

Are they synchronised? Are they correctly configured? This is where you should start.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntpd

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php

Comment: I want to say they are synchronized, but I really don't know.. How can I check? I using date_default_timezone_get I see that its America/Toronto. Other than that I don't know where else to move forward with this. I don't have access to change the mysql time-zone nor do I know how to display anything like the Ntpd. :S

Comment: To get the system time on a *nix box, use the "date" command.

Comment: This might be some use to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449/dealing-with-php-server-and-mysql-server-in-different-time-zones

Comment: And finally, no matter how you get your web server and database to agree on the time, you still have the issue of mixing client and server timestamps - you show local system time to the user in your app then get the DB server to timestamp the data as its written into DB. I would recommend that you use UTC everywhere, don't show a locally generate timestamp to the user, and just convert the time client-side once its been sent by the server. Provided your server time is correct, any weirdness in displayed timestamps will be the client's fault and beyond your control.